# Python 3.10.4 exe fail gets SSLCertVerificationError on another computer

Tags: ssl-certificate, urllib3, python-3.10

```
python: 3.10.4

urllib3

Windows
```

In short, I created a python fail that takes some information from a site and then puts it in a excel file.
From main.py I created an .exe fail as such:

```
pyinstaller --onefile main.py
```

Now if I run the main.py or main.exe from my computer everything works fine.
When I try to run ether the main.py or main.exe from another computer I get the following error:

```
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:997)
```

Yesterday when I tried to run the same .exe from the other computer everything worked fine but today when I try to run the .exe file from another computer I get the error.
Even when I create a new .exe and try to run it on the other computer I again get the same error.

I don't know if this helps but basically part of the code is as follows:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

raw_info = BS(urlopen(url),'html.parser')

#Do stuff with raw_info
```

If the entire error is need I will crop out some information from it and paste it here.

```
url = https://dashboard.elering.ee/api/nps/price?start=2022-06-29T22%3A00%3A00.000Z&end=2022-06-30T23%3A59%3A59.999Z
```

Comment: show url, so that we can reproduce the error

Comment: @SergeyK I updated the post with URL

Comment: weird, error - "certificate has expired", but certificate valid to 26.09.2022. Are you have this error on apple OSX or windows too?

Comment: @SergeyK windows, I have not tested nor need to use it on OSX or Linux distributions.

Comment: try change urllib to requests - `import requests`, then `raw_info = BS(requests.get(url, verify=False).text, 'html.parser')`

Comment: @SergeyK Thank you, yes this resolved the issue for the other computer aswell. Just to follow up, is there some concerns regarding to disabling the verifing or url?

Comment: If your code will be used in production and make money, then this will be a problem. It is possible to commit many types of hacker attacks and data spoofing. You can read about this in detail on the Internet, but in your case, I think there will be no problems.

Comment: This will not be used in production or to make money - just for self use. Also this url is of free public API that anyone can access and use. Thank you for using your time to help.

Comment: Btw, this error can occur if the wrong date is set on the computer.